# How can I create more than one array at the same time using a generator?

Tags: python, generator

Let's assume we have 3 arrays, index, a and b. How can I create arrays c and d just passing through index once?

```
c = [a[i] for i in index]
d = [b[i] for i in index]
```

Is there a way to create these arrays with a sigle generator?

Comment: why don't you just use `for`?

Comment: Why would you want to, there would unlikely to be any computational advantage and it would just make the operation of your code harder to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `zip` function:

```
c, d = zip(*((a[i], b[i]) for i in index))
```

If you want `c` and `d` to be lists you can use `map`:

```
c, d = map(list, zip(*((a[i], b[i]) for i in index)))
```

If you want something longer (but maybe clearer), you could build a generator:

```
def g(a, b, index):
    for i in index:
        yield a[i], b[i]

c, d = zip(*g(a, b, index))
```

Comment: I vote for this answer, but it should be noted, that such things should better be done explicitly as current approach is hard to grasp.

Comment: @go2nirvana Thanks for your comment. I kinda agree, but at the same time I'm so much used to the functional approach that I find it very very intuitive. Might not be the case for everybody of course.

Comment: I agree. What you did is very pythonic. And i love functional programming as well. But this one is really a bit baffling for such a simple task as it seemed to me:)

Comment: @go2nirvana Agree!

Answer (score 3):

I will use zip with tuple expansion using *

```
c,d = zip(*((a[i],b[i]) for i in index))
```

Here it expands a[i] and b[i] in pairs using zip from generator expression.

Comment: @RicardoBucco beat me to it +1, also i am in iPhone safari which does not show real time answer updates